# What are templated methods in C++ / CUDA with 3 angle brackets (<<<)?

Tags: c++, syntax, cuda

Forgive what may be a simple question, my C++ is rusty.  I'm working on a machine learning application in C that uses CUDA for some calculations, and I've found the following line of code.

Just curious how to parse this.  It looks like a templated method, but I dont understand the triple angle-brackets '<<<'.  What's going on here?

```
backward_scale_kernel<<<n, BLOCK>>>(x_norm, delta, batch, n, size, scale_updates);
```

For context "n" is passed in as a function parameter, and I can't find where BLOCK is defined or assigned.

Comment: "What's going on here?" <- nVIDIA wanting to have some custom syntax for launching GPU kernels, to amuse/befuddle your IDE's syntax highlighter.

Comment: If you don't manage without fundamental knowledge, you can try this CUDA course: https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-parallel-programming--cs344 . It explains the parameters in triple angle brackets somewhere in the beginning. As well as how CPU&GPU coordinate their work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sure there is a good duplicate for this already, but the `<<< >>>` decorator you are seeing is a CUDA runtime API [syntax extension](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#kernels) which allows the execution parameters of a CUDA kernel call to be specified.

The full syntax is

```
kernel_function<<<grid dimensions, block dimensions, dynamic shared memory, stream ID>>>( ....arguments....)
```

The CUDA runtime API front end expands this syntax into a pair of inline function calls to compiler emitted boilerplate to allow the underlying GPU kernel to be launched at runtime.