# Are triple angle brackets `<<<` and `>>>` ever allowed in C++ other than in CUDA?

Tags: c++, syntax, cuda

This syntax is recognized by nvcc [to assign numbers of threads and blocks in CUDA kernel calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44760667/1623645), but is there any context in which it is legal C++, outside of CUDA? (Any C++ version, including drafts?)

As another way of phrasing this question, is the appearance of `<<<` outside of quotes in source code a reliable indicator that it must be CUDA (or syntactically incorrect)?

(I know that `>>>` can happen when closing a triply-nested template argument, but the opening brackets would need identifiers between them.)

Comment: *"is the appearance of <<< outside of quotes in source code a reliable indicator that it must be CUDA..."* No

Comment: I don't understand why cuda invented that extension. It was just unnecessary in a C++ codebase.

Comment: Do not give new ideas to C++ language committee.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<<<` or `>>>` are not operators (see [cppreference for a list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)), however, you may run into `>>>` in a template context:

```cpp
T<U<V<>>>
```

See also [[gram.lex]](https://eel.is/c++draft/gram.lex) for a complete summary of the lexical elements of C++ (which includes operators, keywords, and everything else).

`<<<` is also not a perfect indicator, although it is much less common:

```cpp
template <typename T = /* ... */>
/* ... */ U::operator<<(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }

// taking the address of the overloaded left-shift operator template
&U::operator<<<>
```

Such cases were uncommon enough to not be of major concern when the introduction of C++20's `<=>` operator broke `T<&U::operator<=>`.
You're unlikely to ever find it in real code.

Comment: `&T::operator<<<>`: clever! Maybe with a more complex regular expression, this case could be excluded, since the `<<<` would not be closed by a `>>>` without opening some other syntactical element. But I suppose in CUDA, what goes between the `<<<` and the `>>>` can be any expressions that return integers, and that's pretty general. Okay, it might just be a heuristic.

Comment: @JimPivarski at least this `<<<` must be following the `operator` keyword, so negative lookbehind ought to do it. I'm not sure if CUDA kernels can be operator overloads. If not, I think the detection has no false positives.